# Does Augmented Enervation break through Death Ward?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I casted

> [Enervation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells#TOC-Enervation) Augmented (3rd): If you expend two uses of mythic power, any creature attempting to remove the target's negative levels must succeed at a
>   caster level check (DC 10 + your caster level + your tier).

on the enemy that has [Death Ward](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/death-ward)

> This spell does not remove negative levels that the subject has
>   already gained, but it does remove the penalties from negative levels
>   for the duration of its effect.

casted on itself (either by himself or by the Wizard he is hanging around with).

Does he or the wizard has to make a DC10+CL+Tier check, so is it possible the Enervation penetrated the Death Ward spell?

Comment: When asking about Pathfinder spells, please also include the [spells] tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

These are two completely different things. Prevention/making immune to an effect is not the same as removal after the fact - the Death Ward works without a roll required.

Answer (score -2):

Death Ward both protects against the casting of empowered enervation, and removes the effects of existing negative levels for the duration. This does not remove the negative level which returns when death ward expires. Therefore empowering doesn't pierce Death Ward in any way.

Comment: The question has nothing whatsoever to do with empowering. Augmenting is a different thing, based on Mythic Power.